# Google maps info window: how can I get its offset/clearance?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google v3 Map with a UI element that overhangs the top of it like so…

[image: Panel overhangs top of map by about 30px]

And I have an info window attached to multiple markers. The problem I have is that when the infowindow opens and auto-pans to be visible within the map (behaviour I want), it obviously takes no account of the element overhang…

[image: infowindow partially obscured, user has to manually pan to get at close box]

…so the user has to manually pan to see all the info clearly or get at the close box.

I've looked to see if there is a way I can get the **offsetTop** of the infowindow from its parent map, so I can add an extra panTo nudge when necessary, but I'm stumped.

Attempts such as…

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.setContent(this.html);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);

  var infoTop = infowindow.offsetTop;
  console.log(infoTop);
});
```

…just give me **undefined**.

What would be great is to be able to set a **clearance** property on the infowindow, as is possible with the **infoBoxClearance** property of the [InfoBox utility](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html). But I don't want to use InfoBox because there are stylistic aspects of the standard infowindow I prefer.

And I would prefer not to have the map pan more than is necessary by using **disableAutoPan** and calculating an optimal panTo for each marker.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried this in Version 3, but in Version 2 the standard solution is to create a custom control on the map. The [v2] infoWindow avoids all controls, including custom controls. Your custom control could simply be an empty space covered by your external UI.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#CustomControls